# Quantum Hall Effect Dark Matter Detector?

Tags: particle-physics, condensed-matter, dark-matter, particle-detectors

Has anyone used a Quantum Hall effect detector to detect dark matter? I was looking at the following animation on wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Hall_effect#Integer_quantum_Hall_effect_.E2.80.93_Landau_levels

One could tune the magnetic field so that the topmost Landau level is arbitarily close to the Fermi energy. If dark matter particles even slightly interacted with the electrons in that Landau level then they would be pushed up to the Fermi level. The Hall voltage would then jump from one Hall plateau to another.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of dark matter that *it doesn't interact*?

Comment: @Danu All the current direct dark-matter detection mechanisms are predicated on dark matter interacting via the weak nuclear force. A neutral current coupling to electrons is entirely consistent with that idea.

Comment: That said, the usual problem with direct dark matter detection is suppressing the background and I don't know what the backgrounds to this process are.

Comment: It has been suggested that dark matter might be [mirror matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_matter) which is a hidden sector of particles that can interact with normal matter through "photon-mirror photon" mixing.

Comment: Backgrounds would include cosmic rays, thermal effects, and a whole mess of other stuff. I would suspect errant cosmic rays would swamp any dark matter signature and be a very difficult systematic to take into account.

Comment: One could do the experiment in a mine.

Comment: @webb All the direct-dark matter experiment go deep underground to avoid cosmic ray background, and you wrap the detector in hodoscopes. That's standard practice and well understood: all it takes is looks and a whole lot of money. *//apologies to Billy Joel*

Comment: @dmckee yeah most of these types of things end up staffed by Morlocks at T2K or whatever.